# How to resolve a stuck cookies pop-up in Instagram on Windows Server 2022?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, rdp, windows-server

Does not allow me to either accept or decline cookies in instagram webpage
I'm using windows server 2022
Note: cookies work in other sites, but the problem only occur in instagram.com
[image: Cookies popup]

Is there anyway to fix this, or I shall change my machine location.

I tried several browsers (brave, chrome, operagx, mcedge)
Turned on allow all cookies setting in browsers
Added specific instagram.com allow cookies in settings